# How set checked checkbox if it's value is in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inputs:

```
  <div id="my">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="names[]">
   <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="names[]">
   <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="names[]">
   <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="names[]">
  </div>
```

And my javascript:

```
initValues=[1,2,3];
$('#my').find(':checkbox[name="names[]"]').each(function () {
  $(this).prop("checked", ($.inArray($(this).val(), initValues)));
});
```

And now all my checkboxes are checked. How must I change  my code to set checked  for ckeckboxes which values are in initValues array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.inArray returns the index, not boolean. Also, parseInt your value because its considered as string when you pick it up.

```
initValues=[1,2,3];
            $('#my').find(':checkbox[name="names[]"]').each(function () {
              $(this).prop("checked", $.inArray(parseInt($(this).val()), initValues) == -1 ? false : true );
            });
```

Comment: You can always accept/upvote correct answer to your question by clicking that hollow green tick.

Comment: Waaaay faster than me, Mehul. Well done. +1 BTW, *loved* your Chrome Extender tuts - thanks for those.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let initValues = [1, 2, 3];
$('#my').find(':checkbox[name="names[]"]').each(function() {
  if (initValues.some(v => v == $(this).val())) {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my">
  <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="names[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="names[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="names[]">
  <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="names[]">
</div>
```

Comment: I’ve upvoted the answer below because the user explained their changes, not just provided the code, so I believed the answer is better. I don’t know why your answer was downvoted, though, I don’t think it’s bad.

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with your answer, and it's great to see the same problem solved in different ways! +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn the value back into a number so it compares with the array value.

```
$.inArray(+$(this).val(), initValues))
```

Revised Example:

```js
initValues=[1,2,3];
         $('#my').find(':checkbox[name="names[]"]').each(function () {
   $(this).prop("checked", ($.inArray(+$(this).val(), initValues)) != -1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <div id="my">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="names[]">
   <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="names[]">
   <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="names[]">
   <input type="checkbox" value="4" name="names[]">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Fixed. *In solving the problem, I used an IF structure. When I refactored to use the OP's original structure, I omitted the critical =-1 part. Mehul got it right from the beginning, and 9 mins faster than me!*

Answer (score 0):

function printChecked(isChecked, value) {
const newProjectStages = projectstage.filter((p) => p !== value);

```
if (isChecked) {
  newProjectStages.push(value);
}

Setprojectstage(newProjectStages);

var items = document.getElementsByName("tr");
var selectedItems = [];
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  if (items[i].type == "checkbox" && items[i].checked == true)
    selectedItems.push(items[i].value);
}
console.log("selected val", selectedItems);
Setselectedprostages(selectedItems);
```

}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).